# How to add three different class in multiple div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery for add three different classes in my div with same name classes. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="main-class">
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
</div>
```

here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name=$(".myclass").length ;         
    var selector = '.main-class';

    $(selector).ready(function(){
     for(var s=1;s<=name;s++)
       {   
         if(s>3)
            {   
                for(var z=1;z<=3;z++)
                {
                    alert(z);
                }
                s=s+2;

            }
            else
            {   
              if(s==1)
                $('.myclass').addClass('red');
              if(s==2)
                $('.myclass').addClass('yellow');
              if(s==3)
                $('.myclass').addClass('gray');
            }

        }

    });
});
```

i want my output like this

```
<div class="main-class">
<div class="myclass red"></div>
<div class="myclass yellow"></div>
<div class="myclass gray"></div>
<div class="myclass red"></div>
<div class="myclass yellow"></div>
<div class="myclass gray"></div>
<div class="myclass red"></div>
<div class="myclass yellow"></div>
</div>
```

but i got this

```
<div class="main-class">
    <div class="myclass red yellow gray"></div>
    <div class="myclass red yellow gray"></div>
    <div class="myclass red yellow gray"></div>
    <div class="myclass red yellow gray"></div>
    <div class="myclass red yellow gray"></div>
    <div class="myclass red yellow gray"></div>
    <div class="myclass red yellow gray"></div>
    <div class="myclass red yellow gray"></div>
    </div>
```

I am new in jQuery.

Comment: Why not with Php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `addClass` with a callback, and check the index

```js
$('.myclass').addClass(function(i) {
  return i % 3 === 0 ? 'red' : (i % 3 === 1 ? 'yellow' : 'gray');
});
```

```css
.red {color: red}
.yellow {color: yellow}
.gray {color: gray}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">
  <div class="myclass">text</div>
  <div class="myclass">text</div>
  <div class="myclass">text</div>
  <div class="myclass">text</div>
  <div class="myclass">text</div>
  <div class="myclass">text</div>
  <div class="myclass">text</div>
  <div class="myclass">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

By this way, you can add n number of class names to the array and the code will work.

```js
var c = ['red', 'yellow', 'gray']
var counter = 0
$('.myclass').each(function(i, el){
  $(this).addClass(c[counter])
  if(counter < (c.length -1))
    counter++
   else
    counter = 0
})
```

```css
.myclass{
  height: 20px
}
.red {
  background: red
}

.yellow{
  background: yellow
}

.gray{
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">
  <div class="myclass"></div>
  <div class="myclass"></div>
  <div class="myclass"></div>
  <div class="myclass"></div>
  <div class="myclass"></div>
  <div class="myclass"></div>
  <div class="myclass"></div>
  <div class="myclass"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `each()` to iterate through your elements and `addClass()` as per your need.

```
var classArr = ['red', 'yellow', 'grey'];
var i=0;
$('.main-class').children().each(function(key, value){
  if(i == 3) { i=0; } 
  $(value).addClass(classArr[i]);
  i++;
});
```

```js
var classArr = ['red', 'yellow', 'grey'];
var i=0;
$('.main-class').children().each(function(key, value){
  if(i == 3) { i=0; } 
  $(value).addClass(classArr[i]);
  i++;
});
```

```css
.red
{
 color: red; 
}
.yellow
{
 color: yellow; 
}
.grey
{
 color: grey; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">
<div class="myclass">RED</div>
<div class="myclass">YELLOW</div>
<div class="myclass">GREY</div>
<div class="myclass">RED</div>
<div class="myclass">YELLOW</div>
<div class="myclass">GREY</div>
<div class="myclass">RED</div>
<div class="myclass">YELLOW</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**  the code works fine now, you need to serve colors in array then loop over each `.myclass` element and set class name according to colors array
position witch reset if the `.myclass` index equal to colors length to repeat.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ["green", "red", "blue"];
var c = -1;
  $('.main-class .myclass').each(function() {
    c++;
    if(c==colors.length)c=0;
$(this).addClass(colors[c]);
//to test using .css();
    $(this).css({
      "color": colors[c]
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">
  <div class="myclass">colors</div>
  <div class="myclass">colors</div>
  <div class="myclass">colors</div>
  <div class="myclass">colors</div>
  <div class="myclass">colors</div>
  <div class="myclass">colors</div>
  <div class="myclass">colors</div>
  <div class="myclass">colors</div>
</div>
```

code updated test snippet

Comment: Probably you got a downvote because that is not what OP expects as result

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate the elements and `%` to see the modulo with 3:

```
$('.myclass').each(function(index) {
    if (index % 3 === 0) {
        $(this).addClass("red");
    } else if (index % 3 === 1) {
        $(this).addClass("yellow");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("green");
    }
});
```

Your mistake was that

```
$('.myclass').addClass('red');
```

adds `red` as a `class` to everything having the `class` of `myclass`.